# Mapping List of Custom Wrapper type to property type

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I have created a lightning web component for Community page. However, it doesn't directly work on community page unlike app, home or record page.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_community_builder) I figured out that we need to create property tag in xml file for every single property used in the lightning web component. The documentation specified simple data types like string, integer, boolean, etc.

My component is a bit complex wherein I have around 20 different properties in js file, which includes both wrapper type object and list returned from various back-end calls. While other properties include string and boolean to hide/show different parts of the component.

If below is how we specify different properties from js file in our xml:

```
<targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="string" type="String" default="jsMetaValue"></property>
            <property name="boolean" type="Boolean" default="true"></property>
            <property name="integer" type="Integer" default="5"></property>
            <property name="picklist" type="String" default="value3" datasource="value1,value2,value3" />
            <property name="backgroundColor" type="Color" default="#ff00ff"></property>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```

I have 2 questions :
1: What should be the property type for - **Wrapper Object** and **List of Wrapper type** .
2: Do we need to create a property tag for every single property declared in the js file.

Thanks